# Uploading only Image name along with some data in database and Image in folder in web content

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to upload image name and some data in database and the image in some folder in project, if the user upload image, then its name should store in database along with some data and that image should some folder in web content, I tried this I can store only image name in database but the data along with image is not stored showing as 'null'

this is jsp code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Image Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="AddProImg" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="imgname"><br>
<input type="file" name="img">
<input type="submit" value="upload">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

my java code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.util.*;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

@WebServlet("/AddProImg")
public class AddProImg extends HttpServlet {

    private String filePath;
    private int maxFileSize = 1000 * 1024;
    private int maxMemSize = 1000 * 1024;
    private File file;

    public void init() {
        filePath = getServletContext().getInitParameter("file-upload");
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        java.io.PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        // maximum size that will be stored in memory
        factory.setSizeThreshold(maxMemSize);
        // Location to save data that is larger than maxMemSize.
        factory.setRepository(new File(" C://"));

        // Create a new file upload handler
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        // maximum file size to be uploaded.
        upload.setSizeMax(maxFileSize);

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/practise", "root", "vicky");

            // Parse the request to get file items.
            List<?> fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

            // Process the uploaded file items
            Iterator<?> i = fileItems.iterator();

            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet upload</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                FileItem fi = (FileItem) i.next();
                if (!fi.isFormField()) {
                    // Get the uploaded file parameters
                    String fileName = fi.getName();
                    // Write the file
                    if (fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0) {
                        file = new File(filePath + fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")));
                    } else {
                        file = new File(filePath + fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1));
                    }

                    String name = request.getParameter("imgname");

                    String s = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
                    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into imgtable(imgname,imgpic) values(?,?)");
                    ps.setString(1, name);
                    ps.setString(2, s);
                    int z = ps.executeUpdate();

                    fi.write(file);
                    if (z != 0) {
                        out.println("Success");
                    } else {
                        out.println("Error Occured");
                    }
                }
            }
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }

    }

}
```

my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>PractiseImage</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <context-param>
    <description>Location to store uploaded file</description>
    <param-name>file-upload</param-name>
    <param-value>D:\WorkSpace\CS4U\PractiseImage\WebContent\UploadedImages\ </param-value>
  </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Trying printing this `file` ,`s`and `name` variables  check what you are getting.

Comment: @Swati, for s variable I'm getting image name but for name variable  I'm getting a null value